# How do I crop an open CV matrix with an rectangle that overlaps the boundary of the source image

Tags: c++, opencv

There is an assert in the implementation of cropping a matrix that prevents the cropRect from overlapping the edges of the source image.

```
// Asserts that cropRect fits inside the image's bounds.
cv::Mat croppedImage = image(cropRect);
```

I want to lift this restriction and be able to do this using black pixels that lie outside the image.  Is this possible?

Comment: 1) create template of a same size as `cropRect` filled with zeros; 2) find out part of the `cropRect` that is inside of the image boundaries; 3) copy this part to a template. I doubt it is possible to do this without copying.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: technically it is possible but you really really don't want to do it. There no "black pixels" that lie around your image. Your 'image' allocated just enough memory for himself, and that's it. So if you try to access pixels outside of allocated memory you will get runtime error. If you want to have some black pixels you will have to do that yourself in the way that @ffriend described. image(cropRect) is not allocating anything, it just creating new pointer to memory that already exist.

In case you are still curious about how this crop can be done, OpenCV is doing the following:

```
// check that cropRect is inside the image
if ((cropRect & Rect(0,0,image.cols,image.rows)) != cropRect)
    return -1; // some kind of error notification
// use one of Mat constructors (x, y, width and height are taken from cropRect)
Mat croppedImage(Size(width,height), image.type(), image.ptr(y)+x, image.step);
```

You can skip the test and go to initialization, but as I said this is a good recipe for disaster.